# Rotating images in Facebook

Tags: javascript, html, fbml, dreamweaver

I am using FBML (yes) I know there are iFrames, but this is how the pages are set up.

To generate code, I am using `Dreamweaver` and copying the code into the FBML box, all works fine and I have images and hyperlinks.

What I would like to do is have 5 images rotate on the page. No captions or hyperlinks on these just rotating.

I have looked around and tried a few options but none are working on my page.

I would also like to know where in the HTML I should put the code for the rotating images, is this after the table id or part of the image code, or is it where the  tag would be in HTML?

I have give an example of my code below.

Thanks for any assistance.

```
<table id="Table_01" width="520" height="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td colspan="4">
<img src="http://i885.photobucket.com/albums/ac58/GDHutchison/Untitled-2_04.gif" width="476" height="355" alt="">
```

Comment: I can't remember the code, it was pulled out of other forums. It seems as though a few people want to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you can't show an animated gif in FBML (because of image caching) without using AJAX (even that is just a workaround), so I'd strongly suggest you migrate all the pages to iFrames as soon as possible.

Comment: I wanst going to use an animated gif, I wanted the code to pull in a hoasted image and the after 3 sec change the image, I have tried a Javascript code sample from another forum but it was really flawed.

Comment: You could try using this:

file.php
`<?php

/* Returns spinner */
$fbml = "<fb:fbml>\n";

$fbml .= 'Calculating.. <img src="URL_OF_SPINNER_GIF" style="vertical-align:text-bottom" />';

$fbml .= "</fb:fbml>\n";

echo $fbml;

exit;

?>`

FBJS:
`<script>
<!--
function mockSpinner() {
    var s = new Ajax(); 
    s.responseType=Ajax.FBML;  
    s.ondone = function(data) {
        document.getElementById('spinner').setInnerFBML(data);
    }
    s.post("http://URL/spinner/index.php", "");
}
-->
</script>
<input type="submit" onclick="mockSpinner();return false;" />
<span id="spinner"></span>`